# GoCD Nuget issue

Tags: nuget, go-cd

I have a project and my agent does have nuget installed - Not sue what I am doign wwong

```
12:01:14.195 [go] Start to build DemoApp/20/second/1/secondJob on vivians-mbp-2.delta.rl.delta.com [/Users/vivianaranha/Library/Application Support/Go Agent]
12:01:14.195 [go] Current job status: passed.

12:01:14.195 [go] Start to execute task: <exec command="nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages" workingdir="EMApp\EMApp\EMApp.iOS" />.
12:01:14.199 Error happened while attempting to execute 'nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages'. 
Please make sure [nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages] can be executed on this agent.

12:01:14.199 [Debug Information] Environment variable PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/bin
12:01:14.206 [go] Current job status: failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a common mistake in GoCD *expecting `exec` task to be a shell execution*.
By that build log, I can tell that your configuration in xml is

```
<exec command="nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages" workingdir="EMApp\EMApp\EMApp.iOS">
</exec>
```

That means GoCD would be trying to execute a file whose path is `nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages`, which does not exist.

**GoCD `exec` task requires you to explicitly separate process executable and all arguments**. So the above nuget example would have to be configured like so:

```
<exec command="nuget" workingdir="EMApp\EMApp\EMApp.iOS">
   <arg>restore</arg>
   <arg>packages.config</arg>
   <arg>-PackagesDirectory</arg>
   <arg>..\..\packages</arg>
</exec>
```

More tips on task setup:

- If `nuget.exe` is not in the PATH, you'll need to configure full file path  e.g. `command="C:\nuget\nuget.exe"`
- Here is a nice blog post on [exec tasks](https://support.thoughtworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/213253646-Go-s-custom-command)
- If you don't like setting up process and arguments separately like this, try [script executor plugin](https://github.com/gocd-contrib/script-executor-task) which will start a shell.

### Edit 1

On mac you would need to run nuget with mono. So the process executable is  `mono`:

```
<exec command="mono" workingdir="EMApp\EMApp\EMApp.iOS">
   <arg>/path/to/nuget</arg>
   <arg>restore</arg>
   <arg>packages.config</arg>
   <arg>-PackagesDirectory</arg>
   <arg>..\..\packages</arg>
</exec>
```

Comment: It's same. I am on a mac

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the build details to be more verbose? Also, from when i do it I have the build use the nuget.exe saved in the source control, not on the build agent